# Grabbing one column in poorly-formed table using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm iterating through a .csv of contracts, trying to extract a single column from a website.

Here's an example of the website: https://www.austintexas.gov/financeonline/contract_catalog/OCCViewMA.cfm?cd=CT&dd=6100&id=13060600641

I want to grab the column labeled "Commodity Description" from table at the end of the webpage. However, I cannot figure out how to grab columns -- just rows.

Here is the code I'm currently working with

```
def scraper(first, second, third):
    url = "https://www.austintexas.gov/financeonline/contract_catalog/OCCViewMA.cfm?cd=%s&dd=%d&id=%s" % (first, second, third)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    foundtext = soup.find('td',text="Commodity Description")
    table = foundtext.findPrevious('table')
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    second_column = []
    for row in rows:
        print row.contents
```

I want the final output return to be the text from all the rows in that column with return carriages between the rows.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every row found, find all `td` elements and get the desired one by index:

```
table = soup.find('td', text="Commodity Description").find_parent("table")
for row in table.select("tr")[2:]:  # skipping the header rows
    cell = row.find_all("td")[1]
    print(cell.get_text())
    print("----")
```

Prints:

```
WATERLINE REPLACEMENTCONSTRUCTION, PIPELINEPER YUEJIAO LIU, ADD THE REMAINING FUNDS BACK INTO THIS FUNDING LINE  //   PEMBERTON HEIGHTS PHASE III PROJECT  ++   ENC.  $53,209.97
----
WATERLINE REPLACEMENTCONSTRUCTION, PIPELINEPEMBERTON HEIGHTS PHASE III PROJECT
----
WATERLINE REPLACEMENTCONSTRUCTION, PIPELINEPEMBERTON HEIGHTS PHASE III PROJECT
----
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a bunch